# How to correctly destructure?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a syntax error in IE11 using @material-ui/core in the following line of bundle.js:

```
const withStyles = (stylesOrCreator, options = {}) => Component => { const {
withTheme = false,
flip = null,
name } = options
```

Arrow functions worked before installing @material-ui
This is my .babelrc:

```
{"presets": ["react", "env", "stage-2"],
 "plugins": ["transform-async-to-generator", 
"transform-es2015-arrow-functions" ,"transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-async-functions", ["transform-runtime", {
"polyfill": true,
"regenerator": true
 }]]
}
```

react v16.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), try using plugin [ES2015 destructuring transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-destructuring/) to help resolve this issue:

```
{
 "presets": ["react", "env", "stage-2"],
 "plugins": [
   "transform-async-to-generator", 
   "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
   "transform-object-rest-spread",
   "transform-async-functions",
   "transform-es2015-destructuring" // added
   [
     "transform-runtime", 
     {
       "polyfill": true,
       "regenerator": true
     }
   ]
 ]
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue while testing on IE11. I didn't want to have to use Babel on Material UI's code as they handle it internally. According to https://material-ui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms:

> Material-UI supports the latest, stable releases of all major browsers and platforms. We also support Internet Explorer 11. You don't need to provide any JavaScript polyfill as we manage unsupported browser features internally and in isolation.

Later I discovered that we had some incorrect imports and corrected them:

```
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/es/Typography/Typography' // incorrect
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography' // correct
```

The direct import of the es module was breaking MUI's internal compatibility handling.